# Can a nation be "them"?

Tags: word-usage

Can a nation be referred to as "them"? 
e.g.

> The special privileges accorded to the nation of Gregonia were taken away from them.

Comment: *them* here can only refer to the privileges. You can say that, but it doesn't mean much - the privileges were taken away from themselves. It's certainly grammatical, but *them* does not refer to the nation.

Comment: If you're asking whether there's anything special about a nation as opposed to a town or a team, a county or a company, an abbey or an army, there's not.

Whether any of them should be thought of singly as a group with one mind and voice or plurally as a number of individuals comes up about every three weeks in some variant of "it or they", QV.

Comment: @Drew You should consider deleting that. 'The guns issued to the staff  were later taken back off them.'

Comment: Here, I'd say that notional agreement after 'the nation of Georgia' is far less natural sounding than after say 'the team'. I'd switch to 'the citizens of Georgia'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think there's a difference. "staff" is a collective noun, you're giving guns to all the people in that colleciton. But when you give privileges to a nation, you're not giving those privileges to the citizens, you're giving the privileges to the nation as a separate entity.

Comment: @Barmar There needs to be logic if you're going to use _logical agreement_. Most Brits would use 'England was saved by a few brave men in their fighter planes.' but 'England were heavily defeated in the recent test series against Australia.' Collective nouns (some might put 'England' in a slightly different class when used with 'are', but the grammar is the same) are more numerous than some might think. But as I've said, 'The nation of X' lends itself far less readily to plural agreement than 'X' (eg Georgia) itself.

Comment: The special privileges [...] were taken away. (Full stop.) No need for more.

Comment: @Barmar: I agree, and I suspect this is also a BrE vs AmE thing - but I could be wrong. We yanks would (IMHO) **never say** *The nation are happy, now that DT is President*. And we would **never** say *England were heavily defeated in the recent...*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I agree with this much of what you wrote: *'The nation of X' lends itself far less readily to plural agreement than 'X' (eg Georgia) itself.* But I'd probably remove the "*far*" for AmE, since both are rare.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth in your example  'England were heavily defeated in the recent test series against Australia' is England the nation or is it a team?  If a team, then like the Toronto Maple Leafs or the Montreal Canadiens, I can understand the use of a plural.  But if England is the nation, then it sounds odd to my Canadian ear.

Comment: "England" is almost certainly "England cricket team".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *them* can be used to refer to a nation. Here's an example (emphasis, mine):

> Negotiations are held with *each candidate country* to determine *their* ability to apply EU legislation (acquis) and examine their possible request for transition periods.
> [- European Commission](http://ec.europa.eu/environment/enlarg/candidates.htm)

There are a couple of ways to think about this use of *they*/*their*/*them*:

1. as a [gender-neutral third-person singular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) term, agreeing with *the nation* that is treated as a ([legal fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_fiction)) person; or
2. as a third-person plural term, agreeing with *the nation* as a collection of individuals.

The latter is considered to be more BrE (British English) than AmE (American English), but here's an interesting historical note from [Learning English](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-do-does-you-understand-subject-verb-agreement/2977592.html) (the menu items on the page include "US CONSTITUTION" and "PEOPLE IN AMERICA", so I'll consider this source to be talking about AmE):

> Country names, even if they end in –*s*, are still singular. For example, “The Philippines is a country in Asia.” However, if you are speaking about people of the country, use the plural. For example, “The Filipinos are friendly.”
>
> The United States is a singular noun. But this was not always true. Before the American Civil War in the 1860s, many people said, “The United States *are*,” instead of “The United States *is*”.
>
> Civil War historian Shelby Foote said the change from are to is shows a change in American thinking. Before the Civil War, many people thought of the United States as a collection of independent states. After the Civil War, more Americans thought of themselves as a single country. As Mr. Foote famously said, the Civil War “made us an *is*.”

Comment: That's completely different. *taken away from the nation* ~ *taken away from them* does not correspond to your case #1. (It arguably corresponds to #2, for BrE.) And we don't say *The **Philippines** are friendly.* And what is said about the usage of "United States" is entirely irrelevant here (though it is of course true and interesting).

Comment: I’ll take each point in turn. The example I cited was “... to determine their ability ...” - I don’t see the problem you’re highlighting. There’s no argument about plurality based on spelling (cf your *The Philippines* example). The closing quote in my answer related to a possible motivation for the AmE oft-quoted admission of only the singular in this context.

Comment: @Drew Further on case 1: if we treat *the nation* as a person (as a legal fiction), we can use the genderless first-person singular *they*. I don't see the lack of correspondence you cite.

Comment: It looks perfectly fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is ambiguous.
It could mean special privileges 'to the **citizens** of ...' were taken 'away from **them**' (for example, visa-free entry for tourists).
OR - it could mean special privileges 'to the **nation** of ...' were taken 'away from **it**' (for example, the nation could enter a team in a sporting contest).

Comment: We've largely got away from the 'Only "The staff **was** consulted" is correct' hyperprescriptivist view here on ELU, but I believe the 'Any noun / noun phrase that refers to a collection of elements may be given either plural or singular agreement as seems logical' view is also flawed.

Answer (score 0):

It can certainly be used colloquial in a negative attitude.

E.g. "It's them Brits again" (referring to british people in a sorta negative attitude. Could also be "It's them hispanics again"..

Comment: OP almost certainly does not have the colloquial determiner usage in mind.